# How to know Image file Size when using SDWebImages?

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I'm using SDWebImages and set image using imageView.sd_setImage(),
now I want to know what is size of image I downloaded.

I want size in height, width and total memory it occupy.

Comment: Instead of using `sd_setImage()`, use `sd_setImage(completed:)`. In the completion block, there is a parameter `UIImage` where you could retrieve these info...

Comment: @Larme
I'm new to SDWebImages, can you please tell me how to write?

Comment: Something like `imageView.sd_setImage(with: url) { image, error, type, url in let size = image?.size}`? Not sure that you can get the image size. Maybe by doing another HEAD request on that URL. Maybe by checking more into SDWebImage differents managers and cache...

Comment: @Larme it gives dimensions , how can I get memory ( image size in bytes or mega bytes)

Comment: The memory size can be found in `SDImageLoaderProgressBlock` parameter. So it should be: `imageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: nil, options: []) { receivedSize, totalSize, url in let fullSize = totalSize } completed: { image, _, _, _ in let dimensions = image?.size }` I haven't tested, but the code seems to indicate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imgUrl), completed: { (image, error, cache, url) in
                let imageSize = image?.size
                print("imageSize", imageSize)
                var imgData: NSData = NSData(data: image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1))
                // var imgData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
                // you can also replace UIImageJPEGRepresentation with UIImagePNGRepresentation.
                var imageSizeBytes: Int = imgData.count
                print("size of image in KB: %f ", Double(imageSizeBytes) / 1000.0)
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

as per your question i am assuming that you need to know the size or dimensions of image url before its downloading for it you need to implement 3 customize Swift classes in your code which will work as [image fetcher](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/prefetching-images-size-without-downloading-them-entirely-in-swift-5c2f8a6f82e9)

then here is it's simple usage

```
let imageURL: URL = ...
fetcher.sizeFor(atURL: $0.url) { (err, result) in
  // error check...
  print("Image size is \(NSStringFromCGSize(result.size))")
}
```

or if you want to get image size and dimensions after download the image then you can go with SDWebImage callback block function as mentioned below

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL.init(string: self.videoImage)) { (image, err, type, url) in
            print((image?.size.height)! + (image?.size.width)!)
 
}
```

Comment: For that article, a `HEAD` request should be lighter than the image fetcher...